# Why don't I have Blend Surfaces node in Sverchok?

Tags: modeling, node-editor, bezier-curves, 3d-manipulator, sverchok

Why don't I have *Blend Surfaces* node in Sverchok with the lastest version installed ?

Comment: Hello, you will have more chance to get an answer on the addon's github https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues

Comment: Please, install dependences